# PowerShell Dynamic Creation of ADUsers from imported Excelsheet

Tags: excel, powershell

first of all, i want to say, that i'm very, *very* new to PowerShell. These are the first PS-scripts i wrote.

I'm currently working on a PS-Script for AD-Administration. Currently the Scripts for Adding/Deleting SmbShares, Adding or removing Users from Groups, and so on, are already done.
I already had a working script for creating the users in AD, but it wasn't dynamic, as in hard coded variables that all would have to be entered into a new-ADUser command. As the code will be used for more than one specific set of parameters, it has to be dynamic.

I'm working with Import-Excel and found a great function [here](https://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2017/12/05/using-the-import-excel-part-1-importing/), but I'm having two problems wih this function.

```
    $sb = {
  param($propertyNames, $record)
  $propertyNames | foreach-object -Begin {$h = @{} }  -Process {
      if ($null -ne $record.$_) {$h[$_] = $record.$_}
  } -end {New-AdUser @h -verbose}
}
      



Use-ExcelData -Path $Path -HeaderRow 1 -scriptBlock $sb
```

The dynamic part of this is, that the table headers will be used as the parameternames for New-ADUser. Only thing one needs to change if the amount of parameters needed changes is add or delete a column in the excel sheet. The column header always needs the same name as the parameter of New-ADUser.

[Screenshot of excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVJBw.png)

My Problem now is the "Type" Header i've got at column A. It is needed to specify the type of the user for adding the user to specific ADGroups. But due to the function above using all headers as parameters this doesn't work.
Has anyone an idea how to change the function $sb so that it starts with the second column? I've tried aroung with skip 1 and tried a lot of other workarounds, but with my *non*-experience nothing ssemed to come close to what i need.

SOLVED PROBLEM BELOW: added -DataOnly to Use-ExcelData and now it works.

*The second problem would be, that the function does not stop trying to create users once there are no more values for the parameters. For trying around i deleted the column "Type". In the example of trying to create the two users testuser and testuser2, Powershell creates the users with no problems but then asks for a name for a new-ADUser.*

```
AUSFÜHRLICH: Ausführen des Vorgangs "New" für das Ziel "CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=****,DC=**".
AUSFÜHRLICH: Ausführen des Vorgangs "New" für das Ziel "CN=Test2 User2,CN=Users,DC=****,DC=**".
Cmdlet New-ADUser an der Befehlspipelineposition 1
Geben Sie Werte für die folgenden Parameter an:
Name:
```

Thank you in advance, sorry for my english and please tell me if I did something wrong forumwise.

Comment: Can you please be more specific and provide [mcve]? For now the question seems messy (I understood it before edit but now I have no idea what's going on).

Answer (score 0):

I see you I would save the excel sheet as a CSV file and then import it.  It's faster and easier to consume.  The headers become your parameter names and the import behaves like any other object.

`$csvData = Import-csv -path <path to csv file>`

From here, iterate the rows and access the values as properties of the row.  No need to import the data into a hashtable, it's already accessible with property names defined by the header row.

```
foreach ($row in $csvData) {
  Write-Host $row.Name
  Write-Host $row.Path
  }
```

Once the loop reaches the end of the file, it stops trying to create users.

FYI, The use of single letter variables is going to make your code very difficult to maintain.  My eyes hurt just looking at it.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'll give this a try in a bit. But is it possible for this to be dynamic? As in not having to iterate through the header row with $row.Name etc.
As i wrote in the initial question the code needs to be able to automatically use the header row as the parameters for new-aduser, as the function in my question does.
So if the table in excel gets a new column, let's say the adddress. Address should then be used as the parameter name and then pass the value to the new-aduser function.
Is this possible?

Thank you again in advance!

Comment: Hi @ErnestCorreale. Tried it out. Converted excel sheet to csv. The Headers of the excel table do not become the parameter headers.
The $csvData looks like this(there are 15 semicolon rows in total):

`Path;Name;GivenName;Surname;SamAccountName;EmailAddress;City;Department;Manager;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CN=Users                                                                        
CN=Users                                                                        
;;;;;;;;;`